# Using Jersey to read form data

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jersey

I'm developing a web app where i have a form like that

```
<form name="form" action="create-user" method="post">
   <input name="accept" type="checkbox"><span>{{acceptLegalTerms}}</span><br>
   <input type="submit" value="{{Continue}}" class="primary fright"/>
</form>
```

On the server side, We're using Jersey (on GAE). And here's what I'm trying to use to read the POST values

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Path("create-user")
public Response createUser(@FormDataParam("accept") boolean acceptForm) {
   return Response.ok().entity(acceptForm).build();
}
```

But it doesn't work... It returns me...

```
HTTP ERROR 415

Problem accessing /login/create-user. Reason:

Unsupported Media Type
```

Any ideas? What Am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

try this:

```
@Path("test")
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public String testForm(@FormParam("accept") String accept) {
    return accept;
}
```

Multipart is something slightly different, see jersey sample multipart-webapp or see http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html. Your web form is not producing it, so Jersey correctly returns 415 - Unsupported media type, because you don't have any resource which is handling "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" media type.

Comment: You'll need [jersey-multipart](http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|a%3A%22jersey-multipart%22) also.

Comment: @DrewStephens Is it possible to have a single path that serves both urlencode or multipart POST requests? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19104413/jersey-switch-on-content-type-dynamically

Comment: Is there a way to submit form with 10 fields, but without adding 10 `@FormParam` lines

Comment: @VukStanković: https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/javax/ws/rs/core/Form.html

Answer (score 0):

Just to keep it simple: in case it is the only request handler mapped to the specific URL (in that case "test") and with the specific HTTP method (POST), you can avoid the usage of @Consumes!