# @POST Exception in thread "main" javax.ws.rs.NotAllowedException: HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, post, jax-rs

I am newbie in JAVA and I am trying to make a service : I want to make a test with JAX-RS and Hibernate (JPA) and here the task is to send informations with JAX-RS to another class to persist an object Utilisateur and i've got at the moment and for a long moment before the same error about insert a new Object in my Database with JPA. When I am lauching my MAIN class for a test, I always get that error: 
Exception in thread "main" javax.ws.rs.NotAllowedException: HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed

Here are my classes (my MAIN, my service class which making the persist of the object, my Utilisateur class which is the Object class which is going to be persist, my web.xml and my persistence.xml). I'm gonna also post the error code in the console:

My main class (to test):

```
    package clientREST;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder;

import modele.Utilisateur;

public class ClientMain {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException, Exception {

        /* String nom = null ;
         String prenom = null;
         String pseudo = null;          
         String email = null;
         String password = null;
         String message = null;*/

         String nom  = "Vidal";
         String prenom = "Fabrice";
         String pseudo = "Doppio";
         String email = "fabricevidal@test.fr";
         String password = "vfd";
         String message;

        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();      
        WebTarget cible = client.target(UriBuilder.fromPath("http://172.17.0.5:8080/creationprofiltestmain/"));
        WebTarget ciblefinale = cible.path("service");
        System.out.println("ok");

        Utilisateur util = ciblefinale.queryParam("nom", nom)
                                    .queryParam("prenom", prenom)
                                    .queryParam("pseudo",pseudo)
                                    .queryParam("email", email)
                                    .queryParam("password", password)

                    .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).get(Utilisateur.class); 

            System.out.println("ok 2");
            message = "Vous venez de créez votre profil Monsieur " +util.getNom()+ ".";
            System.out.println(message + util.getNom()
                                        +util.getPrenom()
                                        +util.getPseudo()
                                        +util.getEmail()
                                        +util.getPassword());





    }

}
```

My service class :

```
package composants;


import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import modele.Utilisateur;
import ressources.FournisseurDePersistance;

@Path("service")
public class ServiceCreationProfil {

    private String nom;
    private String prenom;
    private String pseudo;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String message;



    EntityManager em = null;

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    //@Path("/getutil")
    public Utilisateur getUtil (@QueryParam("nom") String nom,
                                @QueryParam("prenom") String prenom,
                                @QueryParam("pseudo") String pseudo,
                                @QueryParam("email") String email, 
                                @QueryParam("password") String password){


        Utilisateur util = new Utilisateur (nom, prenom, pseudo, email, password);

        try {

        em = FournisseurDePersistance.getInstance().fournir();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(util);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            em.getTransaction().rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(e);
            message = "voila l'erreur :"+e;
        }
    // mettre un catch avec un try plus tard


        return util;
    }

    //************************************** GETTERS ET SETTERS ET CONTRUSCTEUR ******************************************************


    public ServiceCreationProfil() {
        super();
    }


    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }

    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }

    public String getPrenom() {
        return prenom;
    }

    public void setPrenom(String prenom) {
        this.prenom = prenom;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getPseudo() {
        return pseudo;
    }

    public void setPseudo(String pseudo) {
        this.pseudo = pseudo;
    }
```

}

My Utilisateur class (the one which is going to be persist):

```
package modele;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
@Entity
@Table(name = "UTILISATEUR")
public class Utilisateur {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id_user;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String nom;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String prenom;
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String pseudo;
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String email;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Annonce> annonces = new ArrayList<>();

    public Utilisateur() {
        super();
    }
    //***************************************** TEST ***********************************************


    //***************************************** TEST ***********************************************

    public Utilisateur(String nom, String prenom, String pseudo, String email, String password) {
        super();
        this.nom = nom;
        this.prenom = prenom;
        this.pseudo = pseudo;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public List<Annonce> getAnnonces() {
        return annonces;
    }

    public void setAnnonces(List<Annonce> annonces) {
        this.annonces = annonces;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public int getId_user() {
        return id_user;
    }

    public void setId_user(int id_user) {
        this.id_user = id_user;
    }

    public String getPseudo() {
        return pseudo;
    }

    public void setPseudo(String pseudo) {
        this.pseudo = pseudo;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }

    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }

    public String getPrenom() {
        return prenom;
    }

    public void setPrenom(String prenom) {
        this.prenom = prenom;
    }

}
```

My persistence.xml:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">
             <persistence-unit name="peuplement" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

        <class>modele.Utilisateur</class>  
        <class>modele.Annonce</class>  
        <class>modele.Type_annonce</class>

      <properties>
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"/>
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="derby"/>
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="derby"/>
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby://172.17.0.2:1530/ppeDB;update=true"/>
         <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyTenSixDialect"/>
         <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="3"/>     
         <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
      </properties>
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

My web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>Service REST creation profil</display-name>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
<init-param>
<param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
<param-value>composants</param-value>
</init-param>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<persistence-context-ref>
    <persistence-context-ref-name>peuplement</persistence-context-ref-name>
    <persistence-unit-name>peuplement</persistence-unit-name>
    <persistence-context-type>Transaction</persistence-context-type>
  </persistence-context-ref>
</web-app>
```

The error code :

```
ok
Exception in thread "main" javax.ws.rs.NotAllowedException: HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.convertToException(JerseyInvocation.java:1023)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.translate(JerseyInvocation.java:819)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.access$700(JerseyInvocation.java:92)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$2.call(JerseyInvocation.java:701)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:444)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:697)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:420)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.get(JerseyInvocation.java:316)
    at clientREST.ClientMain.main(ClientMain.java:43)
```

I am new in that forum, sorry If I missed a lot of things, really sorry.
After that test, I am going to make a GUI to connect the SERVICE and the GUI with JSF (xhtml).
As you can see I am not english, sorry for those mistakes.

Comment: Your `persistence.xml` and `web.xml` is same.. That doesn't make any sense

Comment: Oops, I made a mistake, I go change that right now !

Answer (score 2):

this error means you are trying to make a request to a method that is not allowed/exist on server side

in your case it's **GET**, you are trying to make a **GET** request but you don't have it declared in your service

your client code:

```
....request(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).get(Utilisateur.class);
```

and your service code:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
//@Path("/getutil")
public Utilisateur getUtil....
```

change your service code, use @GET instead.

**For the record:** you are using REST verbs incorrectly, as POST should be used for ADD, so you might want to change the client code to make a POST, not GET. but you have to change the `@QueryParam` then. cuz this is not how params are passed in POST

you may want to check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9364422/3604083) for passing POST form fields in a requset.

Comment: So I did a big mistake in deed, I am going to change those things right now. Thanks